# get cursor position

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls, runtime

I have an `usercontrol` called TaskControl and a button for creating other `usercontrols` by dragging. I want the new user control that appears to be at the same coordinates where my cursor is. Below it is my code. It doesn't want to appear at those coordinates and the new `usercontrol` appears behind the old one. 
My code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Point localCoordinates = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        TaskControl t = new TaskControl();
        t.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X,Cursor.Position.Y);
        t.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(t_MouseDown);
        t.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(t_MouseMove);
        t.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(t_MouseUp);

        this.Controls.Add(t);
    }
```

Comment: Try setting t.Location after this.Controls.Add(t);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work out that using [Control.MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) static property, which

> Gets the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates.

After move your use control to the coordinates retrived. Please note, that depends on how you architect your UI, you may need to convert coordinates to client. For this can use 
[Control.PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) static method, which:

> Computes the location of the specified screen point into client
>   coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [`Control.MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx)

> Gets the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates.